# How to rewrite a single word in Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite all the url's that contains a specific word to another word, example:

```
www.example.com/one/myword/two
```

Should be rewriten to

```
www.example.com/one/editedword/two
```

But also

www.example.com/one/myword

Should be rewriten to

```
www.example.com/one/editedword
```

Etc...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that is working in my case:

```
rewrite ^/one/myword(.*)$ /one/editedword$1 permanent;
```